# Поменять стандартное notifications

Tags: javascript, html, css, webbrowser

Можно ли поменять верстку стандартного notifications в браузере (Может есть js библиотека или на нативном )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стандартные уведомление изменить нельзя в плане CSS, так как все идет от браузера. Но вы можете добавить на сайт свои уведомления Javascript!

Comment: мне нужно поменять именно что на картинке которую я кинул, сами уведомления мне не нужно менять

Comment: именно запрос, точно нет) это идет от браузера

Answer (score 0):

Внешний вид алертов зависит от браузера и ОС. Например, в Chrome можно добавить свои настройки для notifications  https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#type-NotificationOptions, но универсального кроссбраузерного решения нету